# DIA (Diagram Editor), How to Print Pages?

Tags: dia

I have a diagram I created that is rather large.  I'm trying to figure out how to print it so that it will nicely print over multiple pages, how do I do this?

When I currently print the problem is the elements of the diagram print verrrry large.  Like one button takes up an entire page which is a waste of ink.

What is the best practice (proper way) to set up the diagram in DIA to make printing proper and scale correctly to paper size and so forth etc.

I'm running the Mac Os X Version of DIA currently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you now how many pages wide and tall your diagram should be

1. Select File->Page Setup... from the menu
2. Select "Fit to"
3. Enter the number of pages

Are you aware that "page breaks" are always displayed in Dia (usually blue lines) That's an
easy way to check how your printed diagram will end up on the pages

If the simple approach with the number of pages does not fit your approach, you'll have to switch back from "Fit to" to "Scale" and work out the scale that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up exporting it from dia as an svg and then resizing it in gimp when I wanted to print out my entire diagram, which stuffed up the text sizes for me, but I had changed the text from the default size so if you haven't changed the text from the default size it will probably still look ok.

In the end print screen and paint was what gave me the best results with dia, sad but true.

If you do find a better way of exporting files for printing please let me know.

Comment: sorry I didn't see your answer till now, I will try this out.